# How to source R code from another Jupyter notebook file?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I am new to using the Jupyter notebook with **R kernel**.

I have R code written in two files `Settings.ipynb` and `Main_data.ipynb`.

My `Settings.ipynb` file has a lot of details. I am showing sample details below

```
Schema = "dist"
resultsSchema = "results"
sourceName = "hos"
dbms = "postgresql" #Should be "sql server", "oracle", "postgresql" or "redshift"

user <- "hos"
pw <- "hos"
server <- "localhost/hos"
port <- "9763"
```

I would like to source `Settings` file in `Main_data` code file.

When I was using `R studio`, it was easy as I just use the below

```
 source('Settings.R')
```

But now in `Main_data` Jupyter Notebook with R kernel, when I write the below piece of code

```
 source('Settings.R')  # settings file is in same directory as main_data file
```

I get the below error

```
Error in source("Settings.R"): Settings.R:2:11: unexpected '['
1: {
2:  "cells": [
             ^
Traceback:

1. source("Settings.R")
```

When I try the below, I get another error as shown below

```
source('Settings.ipynb')

Error in source("Settings.ipynb"): Settings.ipynb:2:11: unexpected '['
1: {
2:  "cells": [
             ^
Traceback:

1. source("Settings.ipynb")
```

How can I source an `R code` and what is the right way to save it (`.ipynb` or `.R` format in a jupyter notebook (which uses R kernel)). Can you help me with this please?

**updated screenshot**

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: I tried this too `f <- 'Settings.ipynb'
eval(parse(text = system2('jupyter', c('nbconvert', f, '--to=script', '--stdout', stdout = TRUE))))` but it doesn't help

Comment: (1) `source(Settings.R)` only works if you have a variable *named* `Settings.R` that actually points to a real file. If this is not your real code, then please don't give us "special retyped code", as it makes helping you troubleshoot your code significantly more frustrating and difficult. (2) `{ "cells": [ ...` looks like json, not R, no idea what's going on there. Perhaps that portion of your `.R` file is supposed to be enclosed in quotes? (3) By not including either of the files, you're limiting the help we can provide.

Comment: The problem is when I launch my `Settings.R` file from Jupyter notebook, I see the `{ "cells" : [...."`. Please find the updated post with screenshot.

Comment: When I launch `Settings.ipynb`, I see the original code without any issues. Please refer the code above

Comment: Ok, but (1) that is not R code; and (2) `source` only works on R code, so neither `source("Settings.ipynb")` nor `source("Settings.R")` (with not-R code in the file) can work. I don't know how you created your `Settings.R` file, but ... however you intended it, it is not R code.

Comment: No, both the `Settings.R` and `Settings.ipynb` file contains the same R code.  Earlier I was using R studio and I was able to `source ('Settings.R')` successfully. But when I do the same in `Jupyter notebook`, I get this error

Comment: The issue right now is not about the code but how to source an R code from one jupyter notebook file to another jupyter notebook file.

Comment: I know nothing about notebooks, but ... when you save a notebook, don't save it as `*.R`. I believe the notebooks use a json structure for the entire thing, which makes sense with what you show. Sorry, I'm out.

Comment: Are you looking to extract from a particular cell in one notebook to another?

Comment: No, I have certain databse settings and other settings related to my program stored in 'settings.ipynb' file..Now from the 'main_data.ipynb' file, I would like to call/source 'settings.ipynb' file. Basically 'settings.ipynb' is used by others as well for their program. So whenever, we write our custom code, we source the essential settings from 'settings.ipynb' file..hope this helps

Comment: @TheGreat Do you really wanted to save this settings in a notebook.  Are you okay with another option

Comment: Yes please. Am okay with other options as well.. but am i right to understabd that right now there is no way to source a r code written in jupyter notebbok in another notebook?

Comment: That would need some hooks to get the cell values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a `.INI` file in the same working directory (or different) and use `ConfigParser` to parse all the elements.  The `.INI` file would be

Settings.INI

```
[settings-info]
schema = dist
resultsSchema = results
sourceName = hos
dbms = postgresql

user = hos
pw = hos
server = localhost/hos
```

Then, we initialize a parser object, read the contents from the file. We could have multiple subheadings (here it is only 'settings-info') and extract the components using either `[[` or `$`

```
library(ConfigParser)
props <- ConfigParser$new()
props <- props$read("Settings.INI")$data
props[["settings-info"]]$schema
```

From the Jupyter notebook

[image]

the 'Settings.INI' file

[image]

Comment: @TheGreat I use jupyter only in the dev phase (or if it wanted to share some reproducible code) as it is easier to test and would definitely make the process to production code much faster.  It is not clear why you want to do everything on Jupyter notebook

Comment: Because am not really a software developer. I use python and R only for data manipulation. Hence I feel jupyter notebook is easier for such cases.

Comment: Though I didn't use this solution, I feel this solution can be useful and taught me a new way to import contents to a jupyter notebook file. So, am marking this as a answer. (upvoted already)

Comment: @TheGreat Another option is to convert the notebook into an `RMD` file and get the cell contents or convert to JSON and get the values.

Comment: Hi @akrun - can help me with this post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311404/folder-in-github-is-missing-when-installed-as-r-package

Answer (score 1):

Trying to save a Jupyter notebook file in `.R` format will not work as the format is a bit messed up (due to the presence of things like `{ "cells" : [...."`. You can verify this by opening your `.R` file in Jupyter Notebook.

However, you can use a vim editor/R studio to create a `.R` file. This will allow you to have the contents as is without any format issues such as `{ "cells" : [...."`.

Later from another jupyter notebook, you can import/source the `.R` file created using vim editor/R studio. This resolved the issue for me.

In summary, don't use jupyter notebook to create `.R` file and source them using another jupyter notebook file.